# GoogleAppsScriptのプロジェクトのトリガー設定の不具合について

Tags: google-apps-script

スプレッドシートのスクリプトエディタ機能で作成したコードを
「現在のプロジェクトのトリガー」で設定した時間に実行させていました。

2018年11月5日に「現在のプロジェクトのトリガー」をクリックしたところ、
G Suite Developer Hubの設定画面が開きました。

それ以降、設定した時間の7時間前に実行されるようになりました。
(イベントのソースは「時間主導型」、トリガーのタイプは
　「日付ベースのタイマー」、時刻を「午前6時～7時」とした場合、
　毎日午後23時～0時の間に実行されるようになりました。)

ご回答いただきたい点が以下の3点になります。
①再現性（他でも同様の現象が発生しているか)
②対応策（時間がずれる問題を修正する方法がないか）
③問い合わせ先（日本語対応のページへ問い合わせしたいが、
　　　　　　　　どこへするべきかわからない)

以上、よろしくお願いたします。

Answer (score 1):

Googleスプレッドシートのタイムゾーンと、プロジェクトのタイムゾーン
が異なる可能性があります。
以下のURLを参照して、タイムゾーンの設定を確認してみてください。
https://qiita.com/kawamurayuto/items/e98ce7f38cb572ae616a